# Obtain negative results from a machine learning algorithm

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a set of images of a particular object. I want to find if some of these has anomalies with a machine learning algorithm. For example if I have many photos of glasses I want to find if one of these is broken or has something anomalous. Something like this:

**GOOD!!**
[image]

**BAD!!**
[image]

(Obviously I will use the same kind of glasses...)

The problem is that I don't know every negative situation, so, for training, I have only positive images.

In other words I want an algorithm that recognize if an image has something different from the dataset. Do you have any suggestion?

In particular is there a way to use convolutional neural network?

Comment: You can only train it on the negative situations you have, then test on another set to see how you did.  You are mistaken in thinking that one has to have an exhaustive training set to proceed.  That's the whole point: Train the neural net and then update it from the live data it gets.

Comment: You could get the contours (if the glass is clearly distinguishable from the background) and check if the contours are convex with convexHull or something similar. The difference between the contour and it's convex hull may be a good measure for broken glass (depending on the images). No learning is needed in this case.

Comment: My question is a bit more general: usually a machine learning algorithm labels images in the known categories, each with a different score. Is there a way - for example if I have only one type of object - to get if the test object like those of the known category or is different? (Something like face detection: if there are no faces in the images, I have a negative result).

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is usually called anomaly, outlier, or novelty detection.  You have lots of examples of what your data should look like, and you want to know when something doesn't look like your data.

A good approach for this problem, since you are using images, you can get a [feature vectorized version using a pre-trained CNN on image net](http://fastml.com/classifying-images-with-a-pre-trained-deep-network/). Then you can use an anomaly detector on that feature set. The [isolation forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest.html#sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest) should be an easier one to get working.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical **Classification** problem. I do not understand why you need CNN for this ......

1. My suggestion would be to build/train a classification model
   comprising of only **GOOD** images of glass. Here you would possibly
   have all kinds of glasses that are intact with a *regular* shape.
2. If the model encounters anything other than **GOOD** images, it will
   classify those as **BAD**  images. This so called **BAD** images may
   include cracked/broken glasses having an *irregular* shape.

Comment: Thanks, this could be a good solution. Can you share an example of classification model?

Comment: @DavideBiraghi Sorry don't have any at the moment. But Google can help in this aspect :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option that might work is to use an autoencoder.
Autoencoders are unsupervised neural networks with bottleneck architecture that try to reconstruct its own input.
We could train a deep convolutional autoencoder with examples of good glasses so that it gets specialized in reconstructing those type of images. You don't need to train autoencoder with bad glasses.

Therefore I would expect the trained autoencoder to produce low error rate for good glasses and high error rate for bad glasses. Error rate could be measured with MSE based on the difference between the reconstructed and original values (pixels).

From the trained autoencoder you can plot the MSEs for good vs bad glasses to help you define the right threshold. Or you can also try statistic thresholds such as: avg + 2*std, median + 2*MAD, etc.

- Autoencoder details:

http://ufldl.stanford.edu/tutorial/unsupervised/Autoencoders/

- Deep autoencoder for images:

https://cds.cern.ch/record/2209085/files/Outlier%20detection%20using%20autoencoders.%20Olga%20Lyudchick%20(NMS).pdf